# Print word containing string and first word

Tags: command-line, text-processing, regex

I want to find a string in a line of text and print the string (between spaces) and the first word of the phrase.

For example:

```
"This is a single text line"
"Another thing"
"It is better you try again"
"Better"
```

The list of strings is:

```
text
thing
try
Better
```

What I am trying is to obtain a table like this:

```
This [tab] text
Another [tab] thing
It [tab] try
Better
```

I tried with grep but nothing occurred.
Any suggestion?

Comment: So , basically "If line has string, print  first word + string ". Right ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bash/grep version:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# string-and-first-word.sh
# Finds a string and the first word of the line that contains that string.

text_file="$1"
shift

for string; do
    # Find string in file. Process output one line at a time.
    grep "$string" "$text_file" | 
        while read -r line
    do
        # Get the first word of the line.
        first_word="${line%% *}"
        # Remove special characters from the first word.
        first_word="${first_word//[^[:alnum:]]/}"

        # If the first word is the same as the string, don't print it twice.
        if [[ "$string" != "$first_word" ]]; then
            echo -ne "$first_word\t"
        fi

        echo "$string"
    done
done
```

Call it like so:

```
./string-and-first-word.sh /path/to/file text thing try Better
```

Output:

```
This    text
Another thing
It  try
Better
```

Answer (score 9):

Perl to the rescue!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = shift;
my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, @ARGV;
$regex = qr/\b($regex)\b/;

open my $IN, '<', $file or die "$file: $!";
while (<$IN>) {
    if (my ($match) = /$regex/) {
        print my ($first) = /^\S+/g;
        if ($match ne $first) {
            print "\t$match";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Save as `first-plus-word`, run as

```
perl first-plus-word file.txt text thing try Better
```

It creates a regex from the input words. Each line is then matched against the regex, and if there's a match, the first word is printed, and if it's different to the word, the word is printed, too.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an awk version:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {a[$0]++; next;} 
  {
    gsub(/"/,"",$0);
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      if ($i in a) printf "%s\n", i==1? $i : $1"\t"$i;
  }
  ' file2 file1
```

where `file2` is the word list and `file1` contains the phrases.

Comment: Good one!  I've put it into a script file, http://paste.ubuntu.com/23063130/ , just for convenience

Answer (score 8):

Here's python version :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function 
import sys

# List of strings that you want
# to search in the file. Change it
# as you fit necessary. Remember commas
strings = [
          'text', 'thing',
          'try', 'Better'
          ]


with open(sys.argv[1]) as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        for string in strings:
            if string in line:
               words = line.strip().split()
               print(words[0],end="")
               if len(words) > 1:
                   print("\t",string)
               else:
                   print("")
```

#### Demo:

```
$> cat input_file.txt                                                          
This is a single text line
Another thing
It is better you try again
Better
$> python ./initial_word.py input_file.txt                                      
This    text
Another     thing
It  try
Better
```

**Side note**: The script is `python3` compatible, so you can run it with either `python2` or `python3`.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$ sed -En 's/(([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]].*)?(text|thing|try|Better).*/\2\t\3/p' File
This    text
Another thing
It      try
        Better
```

If the tab before the `Better` is a problem, then try this:

```
$ sed -En 's/(([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]].*)?(text|thing|try|Better).*/\2\t\3/; ta; b; :a; s/^\t//; p' File
This    text
Another thing
It      try
Better
```

The above was tested on GNU sed (called `gsed` on OSX).  For BSD sed, some minor changes might be required.

#### How it works

- `s/(([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]].*)?(text|thing|try|Better).*/\2\t\3/`

  This looks for a word, `[[:alnum:]]+`, followed by a space, `[[:space:]]`, followed by anything, `.*`, followed by one of your words, `text|thing|try|Better`, followed by anything.  If that is found, it is replaced with the first word on the line (if any), a tab, and the matched word.
- `ta; b; :a; s/^\t//; p`

  If the substitution command resulted in a substitution, meaning that one of your words was found on the line, then the `ta` command tells sed to jump to label `a`.  If not, then we branch (`b`) to the next line.  `:a` defines the label a.  So, if one of your words was found, we (a) do the substitution `s/^\t//` which removes a leading tab if there is one, and (b) print (`p`) the line.

Answer (score 7):

A simple bash/sed approach:

```
$ while read w; do sed -nE "s/\"(\S*).*$w.*/\1\t$w/p" file; done < words 
This    text
Another thing
It  try
    Better
```

The `while read w; do ...; done < words` will iterate over each line in the file `words` and save it as `$w`. The `-n` makes `sed` not print anything by default. The `sed` command then, will replace double quotes followed by non-whitespace (`\"(\S*)`, the parentheses serve to "capture" what is matched by `\S*`, the first word, and we can later refer to it as `\1`), 0 or more characters (`.*`) and then the word we're looking for (`$w`) and 0 or more characters again (`.*`). If this matches, we replace it with only the 1st word, a tab and `$w` (`\1\t$w`), and print the line (that's what the `p` in `s///p` does).

Answer (score 5):

This is the Ruby version

```
str_list = ['text', 'thing', 'try', 'Better']

File.open(ARGV[0]) do |f|
  lines = f.readlines
  lines.each_with_index do |l, idx|
    if l.match(str_list[idx])
      l = l.split(' ')
      if l.length == 1
        puts l[0]
      else
        puts l[0] + "\t" + str_list[idx]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The sample text file `hello.txt` contains

```
This is a single text line
Another thing
It is better you try again
Better
```

Running with `ruby source.rb hello.txt` results in

```
This    text
Another thing
It      try
Better
```